# Array element is considered null even though it clearly isn't when using the split method?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to format the phone number with numbers only so I'm using the Split method. However, Visual Studio states that the phone number stored variable, readName[2] is null even though its value is successfully written on a text file.

I've tested the implementation of the split method identically in another project which works fine. I've also initialized the num variable prior to this as well to no avail.

Any tips? Help is appreciated!

MCVE:

```
string[] readName = new String[3];
readName[0] = "Bob Ross";
var r = readName[1].Split("-"); // NRE here
```

Full code

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Ch13Exercises
{

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] readName = new String[3];

        Write("Enter name: ");
        readName[0] = "Bob Ross";
        //readName[0] = ReadLine();
        WriteTo(readName);

        Write("Enter address: ");
        readName[1] = "123456, 2334 St";
        //readName[1] = ReadLine();
        WriteTo(readName);

        Write("Enter phone number in xxx-xxx-xxxx (dashes included): ");
        readName[2] = "452-564-7896";
        //readName[2] = ReadLine();
        WriteTo(readName);
    }

    public static void WriteTo(string[] readName) 
    {
        string path = @"A:\Q3.txt";
        if(File.Exists(path)) 
        {
            using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path)) 
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < readName.Length; i++)
                {
                    if(i != 2)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(readName[i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string[] num = readName[i].Split('-'); //readName[i] null error here
                        sw.WriteLine(readName[i]); // writes phone number regardless of placement before or after

                    }


                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `writes phone number regardless of placement before or after`?

Comment: It looks like you made a copy-paste mistake of calling `WriteTo(readName);` before you have all elements set...

Comment: I've added [MCVE] to show what you should have posted as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `WriteTo` method 3 times. By the first time you call it, you've only set the first element of your array, yet you're looping through all the elements and are trying to write their values in a file. The content of your array is `["Bob Ross", null, null]`. So, when you enter the `else` part of your `if` condition, `readName[i]` is `null` and you're trying to call a `Split` method on a null reference. Try removing all the `WriteTo` method calls except the last one which will write the entire array content to your file.

```
static void Main()
{
    string[] readName = new String[3];

    Write("Enter name: ");
    readName[0] = "Bob Ross";

    Write("Enter address: ");
    readName[1] = "123456, 2334 St";

    Write("Enter phone number in xxx-xxx-xxxx (dashes included): ");
    readName[2] = "452-564-7896";

    WriteTo(readName); // 'WriteTo' should be called only once here at the end
}
```